# Access another classes properties, returning 0

Tags: objective-c

still having problems!

I have 2 classes, and i want to access the properties of one class from the other.

I have a class called MenuViewController, which is a Facebook styled popout menu, and depending on which cell is selected, i want to load different data.

I have created a property:

```
@property int rowSelected;
```

and synthesized it:

```
@synthesize rowSelected;
```

and in my other class, i have created an instance of the class:

```
MenuViewController *menu = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];

NSInteger rowValue = menu.rowSelected;
```

and when i NSLog it, it always returns 0...

```
NSLog(@"%i", menu.rowSelected);
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The call to `alloc` creates a **new** `MenuViewController` instance.  Unless you set a value for your property in its `init` method, then you should expect it to be 0.

Comment: So how can I inherit the property from the previous view, so if I set it to be 5 In the menu controller, it's 5 in the other class.

Comment: You're kind of missing the point of objects/instances.  If you set it to 5 in one object, then you need a reference to that object in order to get your value into a different object.  Since you don't show how the code in your question is related to the `MenuViewController` object that has the selected row, I can't give you any detailed advice about passing or fetching the value.

Comment: Well, they each have .m, and .h and I imported the menu into that view

Comment: You're still not talking about objects.  The source files matter when you compile the program but not when it's running.

Comment: Okay, well what do you need to know? I have a blank canvas basically, when I click on a table cell, a view is loaded... I need to pass what cells as clicked on, into the view that loads so I can load different content depending on it...

Comment: OK, in that case, try this tutorial: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Can you help me with exact code, I'm such a noob with objective c, sorry!